# How to remove a class from all elements except the current one?

Tags: jquery, ckeditor4.x

I'd like to remove the class `current` **from all the elements** that contains the class `current` **appart from the current one**.

In jQuery, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22483062/1941316), we could use:

```
$(this).addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current');
```

I am wondering how to transpose this way to CKEditor. I found in the [CKEditor documentation](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_dom_element.html#method-hasClass) the way to check if an element has a given class but nothing for all elements.

What would be the correct way to do it in CKEditor 4?

**EDIT:** I created [a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rcarree/s7rkev83/) with a `updateMarker()` function where should be the expected logic.

Comment: can you create fiddle to better understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I edited my question to include the JSFiddle link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `document` object and call `find` with the `current` class. Once you have all the elements, remove the `current` class and add to the current element the `current` class.

```
  var document1 = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.document;
  var elements = document1.find('.current');
  elements.$.forEach(function(el) {
    el.classList.remove('current');
  });

  element.addClass('current');
```

[Document API - find](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_dom_document.html#method-find)
[Element API - removeClass](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_dom_element.html#method-removeClass)
[Element API - addClass](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_dom_element.html#method-addClass)
[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sygn/zbtqy0f4/13/)

Comment: I updated my question with a JSFiddle that includes your suggestion. Unfortunately `document.find('.current')` fires "Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of undefined".

Comment: I mention that I included jQuery. Would you have an idea?

Comment: @Kwadz I've updated my answer with the fiddle, and fixed the doucment selection issue. Before i was creating a new instance of the editor, but now I am reusing the existing instance of the editor.